Адаптация объектов в нижней части во время показа баннера unity
Пытаюсь сделать баннер внизу экрана для игра на unity, использую РСЯ.
Внизу экрана есть элементы управления, которые баннер закрывает, но ни как не могу понять, как сделать так, что бы эти элементы управления поднимались над баннером если он есть.
Пробовал прибавлять позицию по "Y" на высоту баннера у элементов управления, но то они вообще улетают за экран, то слишком мало поднимаются и остаются за баннером, что еще можно попробовать сделать?
private int GetScrinWidthOn()
{
    int screen = (int)Screen.safeArea.width;
    return ScreenUtils.ConvertPixelsToDp(screen);
}
private void RequestBanner()
{
    if (!CheckBaner())
    {
        string adUtils = "";
        BannerAdSize banerMaxSize = BannerAdSize.StickySize(GetScrinWidthOn());

        banner = new Banner(adUtils, banerMaxSize, AdPosition.BottomCenter);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        banner.LoadAd(request);
        
        
        
    }
    
}

